# Ubuntu SSL certificate not trusted after creating and installing it

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2

I have just created a self-signed SSL Certificate on Ubuntu 18 and installed it following these steps:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-12-04

But when I goto my domain https://example.com it says my certificate is not trusted

Is there something I am missing here or forgot to do?

Comment: What you see is expected behavior. Do you want your browser to trust it or anyone's browser?

Comment: @DusanBajic anyone's browser.

Comment: To put it simply, why would anyone trust the certificate that you issued to yourself :)? Think of it as an ID or driving license, you can print one on the paper, or even get proper gym membership card, but when policeman stops you, he will not trust that piece of paper, it will trust only if ID is issued by the government. What you need to do is buy (or get a free one!) certificate from [certificate authority](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ssl-certificate-authorities-reviewed/)

Comment: Even the page that you refer to states: "Certificate Authorities can issue SSL certificates that verify the server's details while a self-signed certificate has no 3rd party corroboration."

Comment: @DusanBajic when I have free SSL Certificate, can you provide steps on how to install it on ubuntu?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04